Centralizer bound for irreducible representations of $\operatorname{SU}_n(\mathbb{C})$
Let $G$ be a finite group, $χ$ be the character of an irreducible representation $V$ of $G$, and $g ∈ G$. Then a classical bound on the trace of $g$ is given by: $|χ(g)|² ≤ |C_G(g)|$, where $C_G(g)$ is the centralizer of $g$ in $G$.
I am interested if there are similar versions for the compact Lie group $\text{SU}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and the characters of its irreducible finite dimensional representations. Most generally it shouldn't be possible to have no dependence on $\dim V$, as can be seen for $g=e$. I would be very interested in any power saving on $\dim V$ or even a factor saving $c\dim V$ for $c < 1/2$.
In particular I am trying to bound the traces of the element $g = \text{diag}(1,...,1,-1,...,-1)$ having $n$ ones and $n$ minus ones, acting on finite dimensional irreducible representations of $\text{SU}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$.
References are more than welcome.

For $\mathrm{SU}_n(\mathbb{C})$ the characters are given by Schur polynomials evaluated on eigenvalues, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial. For the specific element you mentioned, I believe some identities for Schur polynomials can be useful. One can try to start here https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/schur.htm#schurS or look up in Macdonald's book on symmetric functions.

You need to further assume $n$ is even for $g\in SU_{2n}$.
